# Vendor Dashboard Field Renaming WCFM

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, plugins

Does anyone know, is it possible to rename WCFM`s Ledger Book in vendors dashboard to Earnings?

WooCommerce/WordPress website.

Been trying to find an answer in WCFMs documentation, but couldn't find anything about renaming.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. They told me that. Any more questions?

Comment: You can try to use WordPress gettext function like in [those threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwoocommerce%5D+gettext) to rename any translatable text string.

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec  Much appreciated!